# Laravel "Call to undefined method" which only happens in production

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have 2 controller functions which call a static function of a class located right under app folder.

Controllers\UserResController.php

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
{
   return \App\User::show($id, $request);
}
```

Conrtollers\Other\UserResController.php

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
{
   // other codes

   return \App\User::show($id, $request);
}
```

app\User.php

```
public static function show($id, Request $request){
   //codes
}
```

What surprised me is that these code run OK in development and staging environment but not in production.

It throws exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method App\User::show()'

What causes it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are the production environment is using an older cached or compiled version. When that happens, I always try:

```
composer update
```

Or

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Or

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Or

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: It works! and could you explain a bit? I checked the doc, is it because of the classmap package is not up to date and why is it so?

Comment: This guy explains is pretty well: http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/

Comment: we have to manually clear the cache? so whenever I push to production, it is best to clear the cache? wow....i wonder is there an automated way.